# Django: where are the fields stored inside a form instance

Tags: django, forms, field

Suppose I created a django form that has a radio box selection in it:

```
class PlaylistsForm(forms.Form):
    choices=forms.ChoiceField( widget=forms.RadioSelect(), CHOICES,label="choices")
```

If I try to instantiate the form and do `form.choices` I get an error that the instance has no attribute `choices`. Can you refer me to somewhere where it explains the magic behind the creation of the fields, and secondly, how can I access the fields?

EDIT:
To make it clear: I want to know why, given an instance of `PlaylistsForm`, doing 
`print form.choices` I get an error saying there's no such attribute. What dark magic is happening behind the scenes here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming `CHOICES` is a tuple of options for the field, the change is relatively simple:

```
class PlaylistsForm(forms.Form):
    choices=forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
                              choices=CHOICES,
                              label="choices")
```

See [the documentation of `ChoiceField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield), and [the documentation of `choices`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) for more detail.

### Changes post your edit:

#### Short answer

You're probably confusing your field called `choices`, and the attribute `choices` on your `choices` field.

Say you've got a form:

```
my_form = PlaylistsForm()
```

You could access the `choices` attribute of the `choices` field like this:

```
my_form.fields['choices'].choices
```

#### Long answer

I didn't know how to do what you wanted, so I stuck a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` just after I declared a form, like this:

```
form = PlaylistsForm()
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Then, using the development server, I opened up a URL which mapped to the view with my new `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in it. Switching over to my command prompt, I could inspect what attributes and methods existed on my form object at the debug prompt:

```
(Pdb) dir(form)
```

This showed me `form` had a `fields` attribute, so I looked at it:

```
(Pdb) form.fields
```

This showed me `form.fields` is a `dict`, with values being `Field` objects, I picked out the `choices` field, and looked to see what attributes it had:

```
 (Pdb) dir(form.fields['choices'])
```

This showed me that `form.fields['choices']` had a `choices` attribute:

```
(Pdb) form.fields['chiices'].choices
[('', '---------'), (1L, My Playlist')]
```

This is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear enough, I have reedited it - I want to know how to access form.choices from an instance of Form.

Comment: @noam - hope this explains how to do what you're after, and helps you figure out similar problems in future!